# Sitecore 9.2 Unit Test Error: Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/configuration

Tags: unit-testing, solr, sitecore9

I am trying to configure a Unit Test project within my Feature directory i.e.

- Feature

  - Activity

    - ExampleProject
    - ExampleProject.UnitTest

**Implementation**

- In Unit Test Project: UnitTest.cs [TestMethod]

```
    {
      string val1= "Search";
      string val2= "en";
      string expectedVal = "xyz"; 

      string retVal = new Test.GetItem(val1, val2);
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedVal, retVal);
    }
```

- In Implementation Class

```
public string GetItem(str1, str2)
{
List<SearchResultItem> matches;

     --BREAKS HERE-- using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext()) 
      {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/system/Dictionary"));
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.str1== str2);

        matches = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate).ToList();
      }
}
```

I believe I have all necessary dependencies referenced (Sitecore.Kernel, Sitecore.Mvc, Sitecore.ContentSearch) but I am still getting error: `Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/configuration`. I have local IIS instance of my Sitecore site working where GetItem(str1, str2) is being called multiple times so not sure why a Unit Test project won't run properly.

**Versions**

- Sitecore 9.2
- .NET 4.7.2

Do I still have to make changes to config to allow for Unit Test?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is caused by consuming static code (aka `hidden dependency`) - `contentSearchManager` inside the test.

You'll need to use a wrapper in your code that would proxy the static code calls. The same approach is used in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Services.IContentSearchManagerWrapper` for `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.dll` in Sitecore 9.3. The implementation simply invokes static code in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Services.ContentSearchManagerWrapper`.

You could [reverse-engineer the code](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) to see the actual impl.

Please also take a look at the article showing [how to unit test Sitecore](https://making-it-faster.blog/2020/01/10/unit-testing/).